# Distorted screen when display shared screen from chrome to sumsung s4 using webRTC and OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, webrtc

I am developing a real-time communication app using webRTC. When I wanted to share a window(whose width is not a multiple of 16) from Chrome or FireFox on my laptop  to my Android app on a Samsung phone, the shared screen displayed on the Android device would distort. If the width is a multiple of 16, it will work fine.

On my app, I just implemented the interface of VideoRenderer.Callback. When I got the I420Frame from the callbacks, I rendered the frame on the Android screen. The codes I wrote to render I420frames are almost the same as the one below:
https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/app/webrtc/java/android/org/webrtc/VideoRendererGui.java?r=6360

Is there anyone who know why it happens and have any solution to this problem?

Comment: Hey, Did you find any solution to this problem? I am doing the same and in my case the screen share of chrome on android is skewed, however, the  movement on computer screen is shown on android but it is skewed. Would you like to show any sample code on how you do this? Just small snippets would work.

Comment: your issue is like this https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4482 right? then you got the fix by using the #12 response or update your webrtc to the version  including the fix in my answer.

Comment: Very nice solution. Just one more question, the screen is shown horizontally flipped (mirrored), is there any way to fix it? I could not find any function for this in VideoRendererGUI

Comment: Ok I got it, there is no flag to mirror the video in the old version of webrtc library that I am using. This was flag was added couple of months ago in the library. I would need to upgrade to latest version of library. Thanks :) https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/575a8024bc3a2591c2090c3a424aae10db306577

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to add one line as below.

```
VideoRendererGui.setView(this, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
                }
            });
```

For more details , refer to https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4482

Recently, this fix above was added to the updates of webrtc. So, you can also update your webrtc to fix it. You can get the details here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/d941b7609c64516f1b93a0909a0bc23c10d26173%5E%21/#F0